# arc diff uses a wrong author creating the code review task on Phabricator

Tags: git, phabricator

I copied a virtual machine, and used a new SSH key pair. But I forgot to change my git user name and email.

I did some commits then made a code review task, of course, the author of the task was incorrect (yes, the owner the virtual machine). So I re-configured the git name and email, even cloned the repo again. However, the result was the same.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have an .arcrc file somewhere on your computer.  In Linux it is usually stored in your home directory.  In Windows, it is usually stored in the `%APPDATA%` directory.  This will contain a certificate string for the user.  Remove this and you will need to run `arc install-certificate` to re-populate it; or, you can simply modify the file with your username and certificate.

Comment: `arc install-certificate` did the trick for me.